# Why can a common vent configuration be too big if we disconnect the gas furnace?

Tags: hvac, furnace, water-heater, vent

Our house has an electric AC and natural gas furnace heater setup. The AC is getting old and having issues, so we want to replace it, and are thinking of upgrading to an air source heat pump. We talked to a few contractors and one option they offered is to replace the AC and furnace with a heat pump and air handler. However, one contractor stated that this would not be the most cost efficient option, because the gas furnace is in a common vent configuration with the natural gas water heater next to it, and if we disconnect the gas furnace, we would have to shrink the common vent as it will be too large (diameter-wise) for just the water heater.

This has me a bit confused. The other contractors did not mention this as a problem. What would the problem be that an oversized vent could cause? Also, if it is a problem, then in the summer months when the furnace is off and the water heater is still running, wouldn't it already be a problem now?

Edit: We're looking at air source heat pumps.

Comment: ignore the first contractor

Comment: what kind of heat pump ?

Comment: @Ruskes Right, I should have specified. An air source heat pump. We're looking at the Carrier Infinity 18VS, but have not decided yet.

Comment: Depending on where you are you may need secondary/emergency backup heat. If so, and if your furnace is in reasonable shape, it may make sense to keep it and use the existing air handler with the heat pump.

Comment: A air source heat pump will be good for outside temp not lover than 35 F, to keep the indoor temp at 71 if it is lower than that you will need your Gas furnace to help

Comment: You have chose very nice HVAC with 18 SEERS to save electricity and 5 stage compressor (wow)

Comment: The code does. not specify maximum Flue size, only the minimum

Comment: @Ruskes my air source heat pump does just fine down in to the teens, only using the resistance heat for defrost. The tech has come a long ways, provided you buy good hardware. You even see mini splits with no backup in places like Vermont nowadays.

Comment: @KMJ which model do you have

Comment: Perhaps the vent sizing issue is a drafting issue. Modern gas appliance exhaust is less hot than in the old days so it doesn't tend to rise as much/quickly. If you spread out cooler exhaust in a larger diameter vent it may not draft well enough. This is why gas water heater makers often specify that at least the first foot of venting should run vertically up from the heater before any bends.

Comment: I live in Virginia, our winters here are pretty mild, down to the 20s F sometimes and occasionally lower. Based on what I'm reading about the newer heat pumps, I'm thinking we should be okay without a furnace.

Comment: @Armand That sounds similar to what the contractor was saying. He also said something like the exhaust from the furnace raises the temp of the entire vent so everything rises well.

Comment: The other factor in favor of a furnace is power outages. A small generator can run a furnace easily but not a whole house heat pump. Whether that matters or not depends on local power reliability and other factors.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the input everyone.